# Game engine versus engine from a given position

Tags: engines, fritz

I use Fritz8SE , which allows the following options :

- You can let play two engines against each other a normal game.
- You can setup a position and let one engine play out the position.

What I would like to do :

> Setting up a position and then let play two engines against each other, ideally with different PLY's.

Does anyone know whether this is possible ? And if yes, how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s also possible within Chessbase’s Fritz UI, you just save the desired sequence of moves as a database and then define that database as the opening database for the engine match.

Answer (score 1):

**ANSWER**:

> Yes. Here's how:

1. Download [Arena Chess Engine GUI](http://www.playwitharena.com/?Download)
2. Ensure Athena has the Chess Engines you desire installed
3. If not - [Check Best Free Chess Engines](https://hobbylark.com/board-games/Best-Free-Chess-Engines)
4. [Download Stockfish](https://stockfishchess.org/download/)
5. Download other desired Chess Engine
6. [Configure Chess Engines in Arena](http://www.playwitharena.com/?Tips_%2B_Tricks%26nbsp%3B:Remote_Engines:Configuring_Arena.)
7. Load both Chess engines
8. Set up position
9. Example for setting up and conducting a tournament in Arena can be found [here](http://adamsccpages.blogspot.ca/p/conducting-engine-tournaments-under.html#e)